# Accessibility in tails

Tags: tails, linux

I would like know if exist any way to activate the accessibility in the welcome dialog in tails? I would want to change the language and activate the persistence, and I cannot doing it without help from a person, and I don't have always the posibility that some person help me. Specifically I would need to activate "Orca", the screen reader from linux.

Thanks and regards, Kathy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Accessibility page](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/accessibility/index.en.html) of the Tails documentation.

It appears that accessibility options aren't activated in the welcome dialog, but instead from the universal access menu.

From the linked page:

> You can activate most of these technologies from the universal access
>   menu (the Universal Access icon which looks like a person) in the top
>   bar.

"Most of these technologies" includes the [Orca screen reader](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/accessibility/index.en.html#index2h1), though there's a small caveat:

> The screen reader does not work with Tails Installer nor with the
>   Unsafe Web Browser and I2P Browser.

For the day-to-day use of Tails, this caveat shouldn't pose a problem:

- The [Tails Installer](https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/bootstrapping/installer/) is only used once, when creating a live USB stick;
- The [Unsafe Browser](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Unsafe_Browser/) is different to the browser that a user would use most of the time - most of the time they would be using the main, "safe" Tor-ified browser;
- The [I2P Browser](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/I2P_Browser/) is also different to the main browser, and only used for I2P traffic.

Comment: So, if I use orca in tails, the navegation will be unsafe? That's a big inconvenience... Maybe I should to consider to install other screenreader... Regards, Kathy

Comment: Hi Kathy - the caveat only applies to the three applications mentioned. These are not day-to-day applications, and probably things you will never use. The caveat doesn't mean Orca is any less safe, only that it won't work with these applications. For everything else, Orca should be safe.

Comment: Ooohhh I understand. thank you very very much for your help! Regards, Kathy